# How to find path to Image in Netbeans Plaform Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I try write plugin to NetBeans IDE. But I have problem with finding correct path to some image:

Here is my project tree structure:

[image]

And testing code like this dosent show icon wePagesBadge.gif

```
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("webPagesBadge.gif");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some Messsage","Example",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,image);
```

of course when i put this image into root folder where i have on my local computer installed netbeans the icon appear in JOptionPane. This path is

```
 C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0
```

Other example is when i not using Maven Project Type to develop plugin but Netbeans Module Project Type:

[image]

this time the image appear on the JOptionPane. I spent a lot time to find answer and I don't have idea how to fix it.

Comment: You should follow the [conventions in Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) which means having the resources like images in the `src/main/resources/` folder and *NOT* in the `src/main/java` folder.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bad practice to put resources under the source package

create a folder my the name of resources under src/main/resources and then try to read it using

```
className.class.getClassLoader().getResource("yourImageFile");
```

So this should do the work

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(PDFGenerator.class
                                                .getClassLoader()
                                                .getResource("yourIcon.gif"));
```

Comment: +1, the `ClassLoader` is the only way I've seen that works both for Netbeans projects and for packed JARs.

Comment: Thank goodness for you @SparkOn ! I've been looking for this for days and nothing has worked. Your method finally did. +1

Answer (score 3):

i found answer how to fix it. Insted of using code like:

```
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("webPagesBadge.gif");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some Messsage","Example",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,image);
```

i use

```
     ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(ImageUtilities.loadImage("webPagesBadge.gif"));
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some Messsage","Example",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,image);
```

and i put image into:

[image]

Method which i use to load image

```
    ImageUtilities.loadImage("webPagesBadge.gif")
```

is from org.openide.util.ImageUtilities